# Slide element down from nowhere

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a component where an element of arbitrary width and height slides down from an "invisible slit" on the page. I don't want to rely on hiding behind another element, because the element sliding down might be taller, and therefore appear above it before sliding down. Kind of like below without the visible slit. I'm trying to figure out how to style the invisible parent element so a child with content can slide out from "inside". Does clip-path work here? Anything else?

```
___________________________________________
|   -----------------------------------   |
----|                                 |----
    |                                 |
    |                                 |
    |                                 |
    |                                 |
    |                                 |
    |                                 |
    -----------------------------------
                     |
                     V
```

Comment: What have you tried so far if anything?

Comment: We need to see what you have so far. JQuery is a good library for this functionality. Are you using it/would you use it?

Comment: Use jQuery [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) instead of "hiding" (overlaping) elements. if you can use jQuery use CSS and triger the animation...

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have a container to set the view in which it will appear sliding, say `#slider_wrapper`
2. Set overflow hidden
3. Animate your Slide in the element.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` will stop the child from appearing outside the parent.

Comment: Yeah it will do it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a built in slide function:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually here's how it might look like:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdLy9pck/1/

```
<div class='header'>
  some header content here
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='slider'>
    <p>
      content goes here <br />
      content goes here <br />
      content goes here <br />
      content goes here <br />
      content goes here <br />
      <br />
      <span>^^ Close ^^</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider').slideDown();
  $('.slider span').click(function() {
    $('.slider').slideUp();
  });
})
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding:0; }
.header { background: #00f; color: #fff; }
.slider { background: #f00; display: none; position: absolute; width: 90%; margin: 1rem 2rem; padding: 1rem }
.slider span { display: block; text-align: center; }
.container { background: #0f0; height: 2rem; }
```